# Could Workplace.SE moderators please reverse migration from Law.SE?

Tags: support

This [question about legislative intent](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118305/why-does-the-us-flsa-have-a-separate-classification-for-computer-employees) was posted, answered, and [the answer was] accepted several days ago on law.stackexchange.com. Earlier today, the post was migrated to Workplace.SE for no good reason.

Our moderator in Law.[meta.]SE agrees that a question about [legislative intent is in scope on Law.SE](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/question-about-legislative-intent-should-be-reinstated-back-to-law-se/717#717), and he even created a tag for *legislative-intent*. He also explained that Law.SE can get the question back only *if a Workplace.SE moderator rejects the migration*.

When it comes to understanding *enacted laws*, users are reasonably likelier to approach Law.SE rather than Workplace.SE. Thus, that post would be of more use to readers if it is placed back in the SE site dedicated to legal matters, just as the OP correctly identified.

Could Workplace.SE moderators please assist in reversing the mistaken migration of that post?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've closed it, sending it back to Law.SE.  Thank you for providing the link to their meta.

Reversing a migration doesn't actually require a moderator, though it's expedient.  If a migrated question is closed for any reason other than duplicate, the migration is automatically rejected.